# Showing multiple Google maps on one page with different sets of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to try and display two Google maps on a single page - both of which have individual markers assigned to them. The markers are dynamically generated through Wordpress from different custom post types in the head.

I've managed to get one map displaying okay with the markers displaying but I cant seem to get other map working. I've tried adding separate variables for the different maps like below but still nothing.

Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var locations = [
                    <?php  $i = 1; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rsl_latitude', true );  if($location) { ?>
                            {
                                latlng : new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rsl_latitude', true ); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rsl_longitude', true );  ?>), 
                                info : document.getElementById('item<?php echo $i; ?>')
                        },

                    <?php } else {} $i++; endwhile; ?>
                ];
            </script>

        <?php else : ?>
            <!-- No matching posts, show an error -->
            <h1>Error 404 &mdash; Page not found.</h1>
        <?php endif; ?>



    <script type="text/javascript"> 
               var inthearea = [

      <?php $inthearea = types_child_posts("in-the-area"); 


               foreach ($inthearea as $area) { ?>

               <?php  

                $location = get_field('location', $area->ID);
                $areacat = get_field('area_category', $area->ID);

               ?>

                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                    {
                        latlng : new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location['lat'];?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>), 

                        info : document.getElementById('item<?php echo $i; ?>')
                    },

                <?php $i++; }   ?>
                {
                        latlng : new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rsl_latitude', true ); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rsl_longitude', true );  ?>), 
                        info : document.getElementById('item<?php echo $i; ?>')
                            },

    ];


              </script>  



    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), { 
        zoom: 12, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.898748, -77.037684),
         scrollwheel:  false ,
        styles: [
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#245e7c"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#f2f2f2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "saturation": -100
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 45
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#d8dbdc"
                },
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    });


    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i].latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'https://rslcloud.co.uk/wp-content/themes/rsl-theme/img/map-markerv2.png'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i].info);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));

        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);


        //Center map and adjust Zoom based on the position of all markers.
        if (latlngbounds.getNorthEast().equals(latlngbounds.getSouthWest())) {
   var extendPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngbounds.getNorthEast().lat() + 0.01, latlngbounds.getNorthEast().lng() + 0.01);
   latlngbounds.extend(extendPoint);
}
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

    }
}

map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), { 
        zoom: 12, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.898748, -77.037684),
         scrollwheel:  false ,
        styles: [
        {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#245e7c"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#f2f2f2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "saturation": -100
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 45
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#d8dbdc"
                },
                {
                    "visibility": "on"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    });


    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < inthearea.length; i++) {  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: inthearea[i].latlng,
            map: map2,
            icon: 'https://rslcloud.co.uk/wp-content/themes/rsl-theme/img/map-markerv2.png'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(inthearea[i].info);
            infowindow.open(map2, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));

        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);


        //Center map and adjust Zoom based on the position of all markers.
        if (latlngbounds.getNorthEast().equals(latlngbounds.getSouthWest())) {
   var extendPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngbounds.getNorthEast().lat() + 0.01, latlngbounds.getNorthEast().lng() + 0.01);
   latlngbounds.extend(extendPoint);
}
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

    }



initialize();
```

Comment: you have error in your browser  console  .. ?

Answer (score 0):

this s just a suggestion  .. and not a proper answer  si not easy do this in comment so

atte the end of you code you have  a reference to

```
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

}

initialize();
```

should be

```
  map2.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
  map2.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
```

then could you some others msimatching map/map2 assignement that create problems or wrong behavior